# Hide all table when a td is hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, visibility

I am trying to create a table where when a specific cell is hovered I want all the table to be invisible.
Here is my simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h4:hover
{
visibility:collapse;
}
table
{
visibility:visible;
}
#vis {background:#008500; color:#fff;}
td#vis:hover{
table.style.visibility:"collapse";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Each table starts with a table tag. 
Each table row starts with a tr tag.
Each table data starts with a td tag.
</p>
<h4>Two rows and three columns:</h4>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td id="vis">100</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>400</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>600</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not working and actually I don't know what to have to include in the `td#vis:hover` part.
I hope someone can help and reply soon.

Comment: *help and reply soon* Am sure you have a boss

Comment: where is your javascript code? Please post it soon

Comment: `table.style.visibility:"collapse";` is not a valid css stmt.... you need to use javascript for that

Comment: using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gWBz5/1/

Comment: i dont have a javascript code

Comment: Arun i guess urs will work yet where to put the java script? in the tpl or css?

Comment: I've been experimenting, but the problem is that if you hide the table, it is no longer there. And if it is no longer there, it is no longer hovered. And if it is not hovered, it becomes visible again! In other words, it keeps flickering on and off. What do you want to do about that?

Comment: I've got [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6QdPg/1/) that doesn't flicker on and off, and as a bonus, it doesn't use Javascript, but it only works under Firefox. Oh well.

Comment: oh yes mr lister this is another problem
well we r using this for a mobile version of our website
so the hover is a click. the table is hidden yet not removed and still can reappear if reclicked!

Comment: Click? Why didn't you say so? That makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/NErkH)**

```
.hover
{
  visibility:collapse;
}

$('table tr td').hover(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you mention in the comments, the hiding is to be achieved on a click rather than a hover, the solution is as follows.

Put a checkbox right before the table, Put a label in the table that toggles the checkbox. Make the table invisible when the checkbox is checked.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="nice_trick_eh" />
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td id="vis"><label for="nice_trick_eh">100</label></td>
```

and the CSS

```css
#nice_trick_eh {display:none}
#nice_trick_eh:checked + table {opacity:0}
#vis label {display:inline-block; width:100%}
```

That works in most browsers. No Javascript needed. See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6QdPg/3/).
When you test this, be sure to remember where the label was, so you can click it again to make the table visible.